# How to implement a simple workflow pipeline fluent api method chaining?

Tags: c#, workflow, fluent, method-chaining

I would like to find a good design pattern on how to implement this example business workflow. Instead of using one giant monolithic procedural-like method call, I was thinking I would like to use a fluent method chaining -- basically, a simple workflow pipeline without using one of those workflow or BPM frameworks. Suggestions on best practice, perhaps a known design pattern?

My Example

1. get configuration / user preferences
2. validate config/preferences
3. look up / standardize additional config/preferences
4. get report 1 (with above input)
5. get report 2, etc.
6. email reports

The inputs/user preferences causes a lot of if/else logic, so I don't want to have my method have to contain all my if/else logic to see if each step was successful or not, and handle. (i.e. I do NOT want)

```
   myOutput1 = CallMethod1(param1, param2, our errorMsg)
   if (error)
   { // do something, then break }

   myOutput2 = CallMethod2(param1, param2, our errorMsg)
   if (error)
   { // do something, then break }

   ...

   myOutput9 = CallMethod9(param1, param2, our errorMsg)
   if (error)
   { // do something, then break }
```

**Sample Idea Pipeline code**
Perhaps something like this? Would it work? How can I improve upon it?

```
public class Reporter
{
   private ReportSettings Settings {get; set;}
   private ReportResponse Response {get; set;}

   public ReportResponse GenerateAndSendReports(string groupName)
   {
       ReportResponse response = this.GetInputConfiguration()
                                 .ValidateConfiguration()
                                 .StandardizeConfiguration(groupName)
                                 .PopulateReport1()
                                 .PopulateReport2()
                                 .PopulateReport99()
                                 .EmailReports()
                                 .Output();


      return response;
    }

   public Reporter GetInputConfiguration()
   {
        this.Response = new ReportResponse();
        this.Settings = new ReportSetting();

        this.Settings.IsReport1Enabled = ConfigurationManager.GetSetting("EnableReport1");
        this.Settings.Blah1 = ConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Blah1");
        this.Settings.Blah2 = ConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Blah2");
         return this;
}

   public Reporter StandardizeConfiguration(string groupName)
   {
        this.Settings.Emails = myDataService.GetEmails(groupName);
        return this;
   }

public Reporter PopulateReport1()
{
    if (!this.Setting.HasError && this.Settings.IsReport1Enabled)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Response.Report1Content = myReportService.GetReport1(this.Settings.Blah1, this.Blah2)
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Response.HasError = true;
            this.Response.Message = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
    return this;
}
}
```

I was thinking of something like this

Answer (score 1):

You are mentioning two distinct concepts: fluent mechanism, and the pipeline (or chain of responsibility) pattern.

**Pipeline Pattern**

- Must define an interface `IPipeline` which contains `DoThings();`.
- The implementations of `IPipeline` must contain an `IPipeline GetNext();`

**Fluent**

- All actions must return a reference to the object modified by the action: `IFluent`.
- If you which to better control what options are available and when in your workflow, you could have the Fluent actions returning distinct interfaces: for example `IValidatedData` could expose `IStandardizedData Standardize()`, and `IStandardizedData` could expose `IStandardizedData PopulateReport(var param)` and `IStandardizedData PopulateEmail(var param)`. This is what LINQ does with enumerables, lists, etc.

However, in your example it looks like you are mostly looking for a Fluent mechanism. The pipeline pattern helps with data flows (HTTP request handlers, for example). In your case you are just applying properties to a single object `Reporter`, so the pipeline pattern does not really apply.

For those who ended here because they are looking for a two-way (push and pull) fluent pipeline, you want your fluent actions to build the pipeline, by returning an `IPipelineStep`. The behaviour of the pipeline is defined by the implementation of each `IPipelineStep`.

You can achieve this as follows:

- `PipelineStep` implements `IPipelineStep`
- `PipelineStep` contains a `private IPipelineStep NextStep(get;set);`
- `IPipelineBuilder`  contains the fluent actions available to build the pipeline.
- Your fluent actions return a concretion which implement both `IPipelineStep` and `IPipelineBuilder`.
- Before returning, the fluent action updates `this.NextStep`.
- `IPipelineStep` contains a `var Push(var input);` and `var Pull(var input);`
- `Push` does things and then calls `this.NextStep.Push`
- `Pull` calls `this.NextStep.Pull` and then does things and returns

You also need to consider how you want to use the pipeline once built: from top to bottom or the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this is a pretty recent video explaining how to build a nice Fluent API. One thing mentioned, that I think is great, is the idea of using interfaces to enforce the correct order to call the APIs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JAdZul-aRQ